# Angularfire ngRoute/resolve issue, jumps to otherwise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angular-routing, ngroute

I'm using the latest Angular + Firebase and trying to set up a login authorization system. I have home.html which contains login+signup links, going to login.html and adding credentials works just fine (logging correct UID when submittet) but it's supposed to route to dash.html but goes back to home.html.

I've figured out that it seem to be issues with my resolve functions because the problem disappears when I remove .otherwise. But I still want (need?) it there I think.

If I'm logged in (but redirected to home.html) I can still access dash.html through the URL and I cannot access it again if I use the logout function at dash.html and that's how it should be.
But I can't figure out why I'm redirected to home.html in the first place.

Here's some of the code, any help appreciated:

My .run, .config and routes.

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$location',
  function($rootScope, $location){
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError',
    function(event, next, previous, error){
     if(error === 'AUTH_REQUIRED'){
     $location.path('/home');
   }
 });
 }]);

 app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider,       
 $locationProvider){
 $routeProvider

.when('/home', {
    templateUrl: '/home.html',
    controller: 'homeController'
})

.when('/login', {
    templateUrl: '/login.html',
    controller: 'loginController',
    resolve: {
      'currentAuth': ['Auth', function(Auth){
       return Auth.$waitForAuth();
  }]
  }
 })

.when('/dash', {
    templateUrl: '/dash.html',
    controller: 'dashController',
    resolve: {
      'currentAuth': ['Auth', function(Auth){
       return Auth.$requireAuth();
  }]
  }
 })

.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
}]);
```

My login controller:

```
app.controller('loginController', ['currentAuth', '$scope', '$firebaseAuth',    
'Auth', '$location', '$rootScope',
function(currentAuth, $scope, $firebaseAuth, Auth, $location, $rootScope){
var ref = new Firebase('https://url.firebaseio.com');
$scope.auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);

$scope.loginUser = function(){
  $scope.auth = Auth;
  $scope.auth.$authWithPassword({
    email:$scope.email,
    password:$scope.password
  }, {
    remember: 'sessionOnly'
  }).then(function(authData) {
    console.log('Logged in as: ', authData.uid);
    $scope.auth.$onAuth(function(authData) {
    $rootScope.auth = true;
    $scope.auth = Auth;
    $location.path('/dash.html');
  })

  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('There was an error: ', error);
  });
 };
}]);
```

And my factory and module:
    var app = angular.module('app', ['firebase', 'ngRoute']);

```
app.factory('Auth', ['$firebaseAuth',
  function($firebaseAuth){
  var ref = new Firebase('https://url.firebaseio.com');
return $firebaseAuth(ref);
}]);
```

Comment: Not familiar with Firebase but it feels weird to me that both the service and the controller create a new instance of Firebase using the same URL. Think the instance inside the controller would have the new state when the one inside the service would not and yet it is the one used in the routing.

Comment: @GillesC: maybe, I'm not that into this either but I don't think that's the issue here since it's obvious that I CAN access dash when authorized (no auth = no access is working). As I login I can see /dash in the URL flash by quickly before redirecting to /home.

Comment: Or could it be the 'AUTH_REQUIRED' that doesn't work? I feel like there's something to the resolves with currentAuth that doesn't go all the way...

Answer (score 0):

it has with your resolve issue.

If you look at the documentation [firebase doc](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/guide/user-auth.md#ngroute-example)
you will see that they use the

```
$waitForSignIn
```

or

```
$requireSignIn
```

functions. I know that because I have done the same thing. Try that instead and it should work